# making a variable an instance of a class

Tags: c#, java

I'm in a-level computing and I was wondering if someone could please tell me the definition of this. If I have a class with methods etc, then I make another class where I kind of generate a variable of that first class. What is this actually called?
It's the variable definition I'm after shown below "whatisThis" is this a class object?

```
MyClass1
{
  ...
}

MyClass2
{
   MyClass1 whatisThis = new MyClass1();
}
```

Comment: I cut the C++ tag, because this is not particularly C++ related.

Comment: It's not particularly C# or Java related either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally:

```
class ClassName
{

  //... class/object level member variables can be here (also called fields)

  void MethodName()
  {
    //... method level variables can be here (also called local variables)
  }

  //... class/object level member variables can be here (also called fields)

}
```

- Is the member variable **class** or **object** level ?

  - **class level** variables **use** the **`static`** modifier
  - **object level** variables **DO NOT use** the **`static`** modifier

So in the definition of the class MyClass2 you've got one object level member variable with name `whatisThis` and with type `MyClass1`. (It is object level variable, because there is no `static` keyword)

---

Now to the definition of the variable itself. Let's divide this definition into 3 parts:

```
MyClass1 whatisThis = new MyClass1();
```

1. **`MyClass1 whatisThis`**

   - This is the variable definition
   - Variable is of type **`MyClass1`**, this is the type name, same as **`int`** in **`int i;`**
   - Variable has name **`whatisThis`**, this is the variable name, same as **`i`** in **`int i;`**
2. **`=`**

   - This is assignment operator
   - Assigns reference to object into the variable whatisThis
3. **`new MyClass1()`**

   - This is instantiation of the object
   - object has type of **`MyClass1`**
   - object has no name, it only has its address in heap memory

---

Also, let's define, what is happening in memory, when the line is executed (this line is only executed, when **`MyClass2`** gets instantiated):

1. **`MyClass1 whatisThis`**

   - empty reference is created in the instance of MyClass2 in the heap
2. **`=`**

   - empty **reference is filled** with the address of new **`MyClass1`** type object in the heap
3. **`new MyClass1()`**

   - object of type **`MyClass1`** is instantiated in the **heap**

---

**So the final answer is:**

In the class `MyClass2`, you are **defining the object-level variable `whatisThis`** of type `MyClass1` and you are **initializing it** with reference to object instance of type `MyClass1` that is instantiated on heap.

Answer (score 2):

That is an instance field that is initialized to a new instance; *encapsulation* of a `MyClass1` would be my description. If you were re-exposing an interface common to both types, then, it might be *decoration*.

Of course, with no methods, a private field can't do a lot ;p

So to clarify:

- `whatisThis` is a field (`private` and per-instance, in this case) of type `MyClass1`
- `new MyClass1()` is a new object of type `MyClass1`
- the reference to the new object is then assigned to `whatisThis` during construction; field initializers (to use the name of this assignment) typically happen *before* any custom constructors are invoked

Comment: the reason i ask is I have a table wher im listing all my variables and there types, so like x is int, bob is string, I got lost when I had to put a type on this "whatisThis" variable :S

Comment: @New: Just put `MyClass1` there. :)

Comment: perfect, thank you all :) sorry for the noob question it was just confusing me but now it is more understandable. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

That's just what it looks like - a member variable, and additionally it gets directly initialized. It isn't any different from primitive types like `int` and the likes. You can use it at your will inside of your `MyClass2`.

Comment: so member variable or class object, what would be the correct term?

Comment: Not 'or'. It's a member variable *and* a class object, that is, an object of class `MyClass1` that is a variable inside `MyClass2`.

Comment: @NewNoobOntheBlock in C#, a "field" is the most specific term; possibly disambiguating between an *instance* field vs a `static` field.

Comment: The member variable `whatisThis` is a reference to the class object that is created by `new MyClass()`. If you did `MyClass anotherMemberVariable = whatisThis`, `anotherMemberVariable` is a different member variable that holds a reference to the same class object as `whatisThis`.

Comment: perfect, thank you all :) sorry for the noob question it was just confusing me but now it is more understandable. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`What is this actually called?`

You are declaring a new object of `MyClass1` with operator `new` (which allocates memory for the object)

`"whatisThis" is this a class object?`

Yes